# Question regarding business name, abbreviation, and comma

Tags: punctuation

If I am writing a company name, followed by parentheses (for an abbreviation), do I then use another comma after the closing parenthesis??

i.e. The samples were sent to ABC Analytical, Inc. (ABC) in Jacksonville, Florida, for analysis. 
OR 
The samples were sent to ABC Analytical, Inc., (ABC) in Jacksonville, Florida, for analysis.
OR
The samples were sent to ABC Analytical, Inc. (ABC), in Jacksonville, Florida, for analysis.

Comment: I'd use "The samples were sent to ABC Analytical, Inc. (ABC) in Jacksonville, Florida (no comma here) for analysis." There is no need for the other commas.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the comma should come after the parentheses, if the comma occurs at all (and it must occur if there is a comma after "Florida").

See here for a description of comma usage with relation to parentheses: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-parenthesis-or-after/

As described in the article:

> Generally speaking, commas should never be placed before parentheses.

As per Yosef's comment on your question, the comma may not always be necessary at all. But if you're going to use a comma after "Florida," then you should also use a comma after the closing parenthesis. In this case, "in Jacksonville, Florida" is a parenthetical clause, which should be enclosed by *parenthetical commas* on both sides, unless they are omitted on both sides, which is also sometimes acceptable.

See the section on parenthetical commas in *The Elements of Style* by Strunk and White.

http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html

> ...whether the interruption be slight or considerable... never omit one comma and leave the other.

For an example that would better illustrate the importance of the comma after the parentheses, consider another example phrase:

> The samples were sent to ABC Analytical, Inc. (ABC), a company specializing in unique punctuation problems, for analysis.

In this example, the commas before and after "a company specializing in unique punctuation problems" are necessary parenthetical commas.  If the first comma were placed before "(ABC)," it would become unclear that the abbreviation in the parentheses applied to the business, as opposed to functioning as a separate supplemental clause before the phrase "a company specializing..."

> The samples were sent to ABC Analytical, Inc., (ABC) a company specializing in unique punctuation problems, for analysis."

To address another aspect of your question, which seems to be about company abbreviations specifically, there is no special rule apart from the general rules for using parentheses with commas.